# How to stop HSQLDB from command line

Tags: junit4, hsqldb

The following is the syntax I use to start my HSQL database before running junit tests.
java -cp ./hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:mydb --dbname.0 xdb

What is the syntax to stop this database from the command line?

```
Thank you. I made progress but now get this error.

I get this error when attempting to shutdown.

Failed to get a connection to 'jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\My Projects\Libraries\junit\m
ydb;shutdown=true' as user "SA".
Cause: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@
74715985[file =C:\My Projects\Libraries\junit\mydb.lck, exists=true, locked=fals
e, valid=false, ] method: checkHeartbeat read: 2014-01-31 19:06:52 heartbeat - r
ead: -9919 ms. 

My START command.
java -cp ./hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:mydb --dbname.0 xdb

My sqltool.rc
# A personal, local, persistent database 
urlid xdb
url jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\My Projects\Libraries\junit\mydb;shutdown=true
username SA
password

My STOP command.
java -jar sqltool.jar --sql 'SHUTDOWN;' xdb
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue, need to use localhost in my sqltool.rc file.

My START command:

```
java -cp ./hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:mydb --dbname.0 xdb
```

My sqltool.rc:

```
urlid xdb
url jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb;shutdown=true
username SA
password
```

My STOP command:

```
java -jar sqltool.jar --sql "SHUTDOWN;" xdb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLTool which is a command line utility supplied as a jar with HSQLDB. There is an example for Unix, but you can use a similar command in other operating systems.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/unix-chapt.html#uxc_shutdown

Also see the Utilities Guide for more information:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/index.html